# Latitude/Longitude coordinates to BCD in C#

Tags: c#, coordinates, bcd

I am writing C# code to program geo-fences on a GPS tracker (Sinowell G102). The geo-fences are rectangular. I basically have to take the top-left corner coordinate, and bottom-right corner coordinate, and program it into the tracker. Now, the tracker expects these coordinates in BCD format (Binary-Coded Decimal). Each coordinate being 4 bytes long. Now, I figured how to convert a positive latitude or longitude coordinate into BCD - according to the tracker's protocol manual, a coordinate such as:

**22° 33.995′**  (i.e. 22 degrees North, 33.995 minutes East)

becomes the four bytes **02 23 39 95**

Which is pretty straight forward. My problem, however, is that I don't know how to tackle the negative coordinates of the Southern Hemisphere (such as -25° 33.995′, as we have here in South Africa)

I managed to get in touch with the manufacturers of this tracker, but unfortunately it's a Chinese firm, and their English is not very good. They did however send me the following image:

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't fully understand this code. I would greatly appreciate any help.... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (val&0x80000000)
```

This if statement will be true if the high bit is set. 0x80000000 in binary is a 1 followed by all zeros.

```
val&0x7FFFFFFF
```

This statement will set the high bit to zero.

```
0-(val&0x7FFFFFFF)
```

This negates the value after setting the high bit to zero.

So, reversing this, you'll want to convert the absolute value (`abs(raw)`) to binary using your existing algorithm.  Say the original value is in a variable called `raw`, and the binary is in a variable called `binary`.  If raw is negative, you'll need to set the high bit on `binary`.  Like this:

```
if (raw < 0) {
    binary = binary | 0x80000000;
}
```

& and | are bitwise operations.  The apply and/or logic to each of the bits in the arguments.  So 0x1&0x0 = 0, 0x1&0x1 = 1, 0x0|0x0 = 0x0, and 0x0|0x1 = 0x1.

Comment: I couldn't have hoped for a better answer. Thank you Nick. I will try it out tonight.